# Autoincrement list in Word 2016

Tags: ms-word, autoformatting, requirements-management

I am creating a technical specification with Word 2016 and want to automize formatting of requirements that I will describe. Throughout the document I will have different chapters and sections where I will put my requirements, but want to maintain the requirements formatting fixed throughout the document. Each requirement will consist of a requirement ID and requirement text. I want the requirement ID to autoincrement as soon as I insert a new requirement to the document, i.e.:
IRD_001 requirement text
IRD_002 requirement text
IRD_003 requirement text

Requirement ID needs to be unique and always start with 'IRD_'. Requirements will be scattered throughout the document. It can happen that with version 2.0 of the document I will need to add or remove some requirements. The existing list of requirements shall not be modified though, i.e.

IRD_001 requirement text
IRD_004 added requirement text
IRD_002 requirement text
IRD_003 requirement text

How can I achieve this with MS Word?

Answer (score 0):

not easy. I had to do the same thing a few years ago. I added in the requirement ID the section name and kept section small to not have too many number.

Example for the amplifiers section:

RQ-AMP-001: Blabla...

RQ-AMP-002:

Last year, I converted the file to XML for importing inside TestLink which is able to manage requirement (see testlink.org) and do traceability with test case.